# Neo4J load CSV and create relationships doesn't import all data

Tags: csv, neo4j, cypher

I am using following CSV load Cypher statement to import csv file with about 3.5m records. But it only imports about 3.2m. So about 300000 records are not imported.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///path/to/csvfile.csv") as line
CREATE (ticket:Ticket {id: line.transaction_hash, from_stop: toInt(line.from_stop), to_stop: toInt(line.to_stop), ride_id: toInt(line.ride_id), price: toFloat(line.price)})
MATCH (from_stop:Stop)-[r:RELATES]->(to_stop:Stop) WHERE toInt(line.route_id) in r.routes
CREATE (from_stop)-[:CONNECTS {ticket_id: ID(ticket)}]->(to_stop)
```

Note that Stop nodes are already created in separate import statement.

When I only created Nodes without creating relationships it was able to import all data. This same import statement works fine with smaller set of same format csv data.

I tried twice just to make sure it wasn't terminated accidentally.

Is there node to relationship limit in Neo4J? Or what could be other reason?

`Neo4J version: 3.0.3 size of database directory is 5.31 GiB.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because whenever the `MATCH` does not succeed for a line, the entire query for that line (including the first `CREATE`) also fails.

On the other hand, the failure of an `OPTIONAL MATCH` would not abort the entire query for a line. Try this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM ("file:///path/to/csvfile.csv") as line
CREATE (ticket:Ticket {id: line.transaction_hash, from_stop: toInt(line.from_stop), to_stop: toInt(line.to_stop), ride_id: toInt(line.ride_id), price: toFloat(line.price)})
OPTIONAL MATCH (from:Stop)-[r:RELATES]->(to:Stop)
WHERE toInt(line.route_id) in r.routes
FOREACH(x IN CASE WHEN from IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE [1] END |
  CREATE (from)-[:CONNECTS {ticket_id: ID(ticket)}]->(to)
);
```

The `FOREACH` clause uses a somewhat roundabout technique to only `CREATE` the relationship if the `OPTIONAL MATCH` succeeded for a line.

Comment: hmm, that is interesting. Thank you for the tip.
However, I don't expect (it should not or there is data integrity issue) that match to fail. So have to look into earlier imports.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an additional approach. You do not want to try one of them out, you should at least test your assumption that the `MATCH/WHERE` clauses always succeed.